# Запрос на местоположение в Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, геолокация, weather

В дискорд боте будет функция проверки погоды. Но для этого нужно узнать местоположение пользователя. Он, по очевидным причинам, не захочет показывать его остальным. Есть ли возможность запросить у Discord положение пользователя или его ip для отправки погоды?(Это не хакерская утилита (: Пользователь сам решит разрешать ли ему доступ к местоположению или нет)

Comment: Дискорд - это текстовой чат, где люди обмениваются текстом, по сути все (голос в расчет не беру). Вы не можете у человека запросить больше того, что вы можете отправить своему знакомому в личной переписке. Что касается погоды, то город - это не столь конфиденциальная информация, и для определения погоды, вам точные координаты человека не нужны, а значит, вы можете у человека попросить лишь город, в любом виде, даже можете выдать выпадающий список с заранее подготовленными городами, и на основе этого отдавать погоду.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать команду с вводом IP и удалять сообщение с командой сразу.
Юзайте для этого `await message.delete()`